# Не могу заменить слово

Tags: c#

Не могу заменить слово "тетрадь" на слово "дневник" циклом for.
Выводится неверное слово.

```
static void Main()
{
    string s = "тетрадь";
    string s1 = "дневник";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != s1[i])
        {
            s = s.Replace(s[i], s1[i]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам условие `if (s[i] != s1[i])` ? Что оно по-вашему делает/проверяет?

Comment: `s = s1;` *(нужно ещё 6 символов...)*

Comment: ну вдруг буква совпадает, можно и не менять.

Comment: "Выводится неверное слово." - какое?

Comment: "инивник" вот что выводится.

Comment: А зачем здесь цикл вообще, если Replace может заменить сразу слово целиком?

Comment: Так делать просто нельзя. У вас сначала **все** символы `т` меняются на `д`, а в конце и исходный `д` и эти новые `д`, которые получились из `т` опять же **все** меняются на `и`.

Единственный нормальный подход - это менять только символ **в конкретной позиции**, сохраняя все остальные символы неизменными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сравниваете не строки, а символы, используя индекс для строки вы переводите её неявно в список символов.
Используйте:

```
string s = "тетрадь", s1 = "дневник", s2 = "Татьяна писала на тетрадь";
s2 = s2.Replace(s, s1);
```

Результат: Татьяна писала на дневник

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0

> Returns a new string in which *all occurrences* ...

Выводите строку на каждую замену и увидите.

```
    if (s[i] != s1[i])
    {
        s = s.Replace(s[i], s1[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```